# Integration of GWT and HTML

Tags: java, html, gwt, smartgwt

Can we keep a static HTML to integrate with the dynamic GWT Widgets that are created. And how will the event handling can be done for the dynamic GWT Widgets.

Answer (score 1):

You have to "attach" GWT widgets to the existing DOM (i.e. HTML) to receive DOM events.

Use `wrap(Element)` method that some widgets provide (Label, TextArea, etc) to wrap existing HTML.

You don't have to do this for every Widget, just for the top-most widget in your hierarchy.
The easiest would be to use [`HTML.wrap(element)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTML.html#wrap%28com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element%29) (or `InlineHTML` if you need an inline element) and then add your Widgets to it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The number of GWT Widgets are not known at compile time. The number of widgets gets created dynamically. SO how should i go ahead if i need to use CSS of the existing HTML.

Comment: You can add/set CSS classes to existing widgets `addStyleName(..)` or `setStyleName(..)`